# Error in my code...please help me to solve

Tags: matlab, user-interface

```
function listbox1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

index_selected = get(hObject,'Value');
list = get(hObject,'String');
item_selected = list{index_selected}; % Convert from cell array % to string
 disp(item_selected);
 textdata=xlsread('stringipdata.xlsx');
 GetColumnC(handles, textdata);




function listbox2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
index_selected = get(hObject,'Value');
list = get(hObject,'String');
item_selected2 = list{index_selected}; % Convert from cell array
                                      % to string
disp(item_selected2);
 textdata=xlsread('stringipdata.xlsx');
GetColumnC(handles, textdata);




function itemFromColumnC = GetColumnC(handles, textdata)


itemFromColumnC = []; % Initialize to null

% Get the item number that they selected.
selected1 = get(handles.listbox1, 'value');
selected2 = get(handles.listbox2, 'value');


% Get the contents (optional - just FYI in case you want to inspect)
items1 = get(handles.listbox1, 'String');
items2 = get(handles.listbox2, 'String');
% Get the selected item (optional - just FYI in case you want to inspect)
selectedItem1 = items1{selected1};
selectedItem2 = items2{selected2};


% Now compare
if selected1 == selected2 
  % All indexes are the same so extract column C at that row.

itemFromColumnC = textdata{selected1, 3};
  disp(itemFromColumnC);

end
```

**Error is:**

??? Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

Error in ==> stringdata>GetColumnC at 188
  itemFromColumnC = textdata{selected1, 3};

- cell values are strings
- I want to display the 3rd column cell value as
  the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first output of `xlsread` is a normal (double) array. The third output is a cell array with all the contents of the xls. You should call it like this:

```
[t1, t2, textdata] = xlsread('stringipdata.xlsx'); % or replace t1 and t2 by ~
```

Comment: Lot Many thanks to you....I was trying this from many days....Thanks a lot